# ViewPostIme pointer 1/0 log appears after screen touching

Tags: java, android

After each touch on the screen I see the following logs:
`2022-03-13 16:26:41.623 30837-30837/com.example.triviaquestions I/ViewRootImpl@d23fa95[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0`
`2022-03-13 16:26:41.698 30837-30837/com.example.triviaquestions I/ViewRootImpl@d23fa95[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1`
always together and in the above order,i tried to google it but found nothing concrete.
I will be happy to understand why it appears and if it is meaningful to me.

Answer (score 4):

It is not an error , this happens when you are using SAMSUNG phones like Samsung A50 ,Samsung A30....., instead of using emulator or any phone except Samsung.